# .dll already loaded in another classloader?

Tags: web-applications, java-native-interface, javabeans

I have a webapp running under Tomcat 3.2.1 that needs to make JNI calls in
order to access data and methods in legacy C++ code.  A servlet is loaded
on
startup of the webapp that, as part of its `init` method, causes a data set
specific to that webapp instance to be loaded into the C++ data
structures.

This Java code for this servlet contains the following:

```
static
{
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("JCoreImpl");
        System.out.println("JCoreImpl loaded");
        m_bLibraryLoaded = true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        m_bLibraryLoaded = false;
        System.out.println("JCoreImpl NOT loaded " + e);
    }
}
```

Things work fine if there is only one webapp (let's call it
"webapps/aaa").

If I have a second webapp ("webapps/bbb") that is identical to webapps/aaa
except for the data set used in the C++ data structures, then webapps/aaa
starts up just fine, but when webapps/bbb is started I get an error
stating
that:

```
JCoreImpl NOT loaded java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library
E:\WebStation\binDebug\JCoreImpl.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

I need to have a separate instance of the native library for each of my
webapps as each instance needs to contain data that is unique to that
particular webapp.  I have searched through the mail archives and read
emails by Craig McLanahan explaining the classloader hierarchy.  But I
have
not been able to find anything specific to loading a unique instance of a
native library for each webapp.

Answer (score 16):

You can't load the same native library twice.

Put the class in a jar file under `<tomcat>/lib/`, it will be shared over all wars.

Answer (score 9):

See the section [I'm encountering classloader problems when using JNI under Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat) on the Tomcat HowTo wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the DLLs to temporary files in a temporary directory before loading them.  Delete the files when you are done.  This way you can ensure that the same DLL is not loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it:

**Problem:**

The problem is due to some configurations of your application server which cause to create more than one `war` or `ear` files and consequently it creates more than one deployed files. These deployed files attempt to have a concurrent access to your native library which loaded in a static block.

**Solution:**

1. Stop your Application Server and close the IDEA
2. Finish all `java` processes from task manager
3. Go to this address of your App Server: `jboss-eap-6.4.0\standalone\configuration` and open `standalone.xml` file
4. In the `standalone.xml` , delete all the `deployments` tag (Don't worry, when you rerun the application server, it inserts this tag
5. Go to this address of your App Server:
   `jboss-eap-6.4.0\standalone\deployments` and delete all deployed
   files and `war` files. (You can backup your war files)
6. Open IntelliJ Idea and go to: Edit Configuration JBOSS -> Deployment tab
7. Delete current deployment and add a new one that should be
   `exploded`