# Loading Native library in Scala Compiler Plugin

Tags: scala, dll, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide, scalac

I am developing a scala compiler plugin. The compiler plugin runs after the "refcheck" phase. It analyzes the AST(Abstract Syntax Tree)
and generates some output. In this plugin, I am loading a native library "scalaz3.dll" using `System.loadLibrary`

I plan to use the compiler plugin with the Eclipse Scala IDE. I set the `-XPlugin` parameter in the ScalaIde preferences.
When I compile a scala source file in Eclipse, the plugin is invoked after the `refchecks` phase and works fine (generates the desired output)

However, when I make changes to the the source file and compile, I am getting the following error.

```
The SBT builder crashed while compiling your project. 
Native Library scalaz3.dll already loaded in another classloader.
```

Looks like the ScalaIDE generates another classloader and tries to load the plugin classes in the same process.

I was facing the same problem in the compiler plugin test case. However, I fixed it using `fork in Test := true` in the `build.sbt`.
But I am clueless about how to fix it in eclipse scala IDE.

Here are few related posts(although not related to eclipse scala ide):

- [.dll already loaded in another classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030792/dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/79145/Websphere/Native-lib-already-loaded-another
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4750956

Answer (score 2):

The IDE uses sbt in-process, so there is no equivalent of forking. Couldn't you load the dll only once, for instance by loading it inside the constructor of an `object`?

The technique is suggested [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tomcat/HowTo#HowTo-I%27mencounteringclassloaderproblemswhenusingJNIunderTomcat):

> The class that calls `System.loadLibrary(String)` must be loaded by a
> classloader that is not affected by reloading the web application
> itself.
>
> Thus, if you have JNI code that follows the convention of including a
> static initilaizer like this:
>
> ```java
> class FooWrapper {
>     static {
>         System.loadLibrary("foo");
>     }
>
>     native void doFoo(); 
> }
> ```
>
> [...]