# Java Tomcat web application JNI

Tags: java, tomcat, java-native-interface

I have java web application which is deployed to Tomcat. Application calls low level `C` library via JNI. Everything works fine when I deploy my application at first time, but as soon as I trying to redeploy - application crashes with following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/shared/lib/libGenderizer.so already loaded in another classloader`

1. I've created and put my .so object under /opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/shared/lib.
2. In catalina.sh (file which starts tomcat) I've added following line which sets library path for tomcat. `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/apache-tomcat/current/shared/lib"`
3. I am redeploying my application using maven `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`

Could you please help me to resolve current issue? I am doing System.gc() but unfortunately it doesn't help.

```
   public class GenderService {

            private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenderService.class);

            static {
                try {
                    System.gc();
                    System.loadLibrary("Genderizer");
                }
                catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
                    logger.error("Native code library failed to load.\n", e);
                }
            }

            private native String genderize(String name);


            public Gender identifyGender(Customer customer){
                Gender gender = determineGender(customer);
                return gender;
            }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.dll already loaded in another classloader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030792/dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)

Answer (score 0):

Already asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030792/dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader). See [Apache Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat) for a helpful answer.

Comment: I've read it but unfortunately didn't get how does it works. If I wrap my library into JAR how do I invoke it?

Comment: If you add the JAR to shared/lib all the classes in the JAR are available to your application as if they were located in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib. So you simply use ist as before.

Comment: before I was using them directly in java since I could `import` it  on top of the class. Since file is not in my project, how do I invoke its method? Lets say I have `AClass` which as method `AMethod(String)`, could you please give me example how do I invoke it if jar is inside /shared/lib? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand: why is it not in your project? Your GenderService is still supposed to be part of your project. You just deploy it in separate JARs.

Comment: Hm.. Right now I am developing and resolving all dependencies via maven. You are saying that I have to generate Wrapper jar and add it as external jar from /shared/lib? Also in catalina.properties I have to specify folder for jars? `shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar`

Comment: Yes. For building with maven I guess you could build it as a separate artifact and add this as a compile-time dependency to your main project.

Comment: Hmm., No Idea, doesn't work. This is how I am trying to import separate .jar but no luck unable to resolve dependencies on compile time.         `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.thehutgroup.GenderizerWrapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>GenderizerWrapper</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/Genderizer/GenderizerWrapper.jar</systemPath>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70719/discussion-between-andreas-vogler-and-wild-goat).

Comment: hi i tried this solution from the tomcat wiki, but when undeploying my app i get an error, that he cannot delte the jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder