# set provided scope in maven integrated with jboss

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have developed a maven-based project (maven-3.3.9) using jboss-eap-6.4 in IntelliJIDEA 14.0. I am using `bouncy castle` libraries and I have to set them as `provided scope` in maven dependency.

1. Where exactly should I put the bouncy castle jar files?
2. What configuration should I set?

I have tried two options for the 1st question as follows:

- I put jar files here: `jboss-eap-6.4\modules\org\bouncycastle\main\`

and

- I put jar files here: `jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\bouncycastle\main\`

Also, I have provided the following configuration in `module.xml` beside the jar files:

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding=UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="run:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.bouncycastle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="bcpkix-jdk15on-1.54.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

However, when I clean and install maven I get the following error:

- error during artifact deploment
- caused by java.lang.RunTimeException:...
- caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:...
- caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:...

Answer (score 0):

The errors you mentioned are deployment errors those are not related to maven.

To add a JBoss module to your application create a file named `WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and add the module in dependency. In your case the file content should be as follows.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.bouncycastle"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

While deployment, the jboss will load the module in to classpath.

Comment: I have not WEB-INF in my src, I have it only in my target. When I add this xml in WEB-INF I get the following error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in another class loader.

Comment: it should be in `src\main\webapp` folder

Comment: I have not `WEB-INF` folder in `src\main\webapp`

Comment: I created and put the xml file in it. However, I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in another class loader`

Comment: I should told you that I have a local native dll which I load it in a static block as follows: `System.load("myAdr\\myDllName.dll);` When I don't use the provided scope I have not any problem with loading this native library

Comment: This is different issue check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030792/dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)